# SharePoint Datasheet view read-only custom field

Tags: sharepoint

Is there any way to add validation (ie SSN) to a SharePoint field and still have it editable in datasheet view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not.. you would have to create your own datasheet ActiveX-control. It lives on the client, not the server.

You could make your SSN a standard column type and validate its format in an EventHandler on the list. This would make the row in the datasheet view error if the exact template is not followed. 
Not exactly the best user experience I'll admit but at least a user can fix the problem and continue and your data will be sound.